# How to call a specific action inside a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have a form which contains some text_fields. One of them is the zip code field. It has a button "Search" that calls an specific action "search_zip_code" which returns the address values associated with that field. How can I invoke this action inside a form_for tag? I have already tried a form_tag nested to it, but the submit action invokes the :create method. If I use a "link_to", I can't pass the zip code entered by the user. What is the best approach for that?

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |m|%>
  <%= m.label :field_1 %>
  <%= m.text_field :field_1 %>

  <%= m.label :field_2 %>
  <%= m.text_field :field_2 %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form_tag("/search_zip_code", method: "get") do %>
      <%= label_tag(:zip, "ZIP Code:") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:zip) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= m.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Why the action "/search_zip_code" isn't reached by the submit_tag button? Even if I change this route to a :post method, it doesn't work.

Thank you,

Guilherme

Comment: Move the form tag outside of the form_for and add a remote: true to your form_tag so that it does an ajax call to your controller. In your controller, return either javascript or json and create a javascript file with the info you want to insert into your form_for.

Comment: The HTML specification does not actually allow for nested forms. By using nested forms you are relying on slop parsing and the results may be inconsistent. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

Comment: Use javascript instead to bind an event handler to the input.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! I'll do it with Ajax!

Answer (score 0):

So guys, according to https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails and your suggestions, my solution should look like:

My main _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |m|%>
  <%= m.label :field_1 %>
  <%= m.text_field :field_1 %>

 <%= m.label :field_2 %>
 <%= m.text_field :field_2 %>

 <div class="field">
    <%= m.label :zip %>
    <%= m.text_field :zip %>
    <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" >
</div>
<div id="address-data" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
  $("#search").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/search_zip_code?zip=' + m_zip.value,
      type: 'get'
    });
  });
</script>

<%= m.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The controller action:

```
def search_zip_code
    @add_zip = search(params[:zip]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

Then, I need a search_zip_code.js.erb file:

```
$('#address-data').html("<%= j (render 'form-zip') %>");
$('#address-data').slideDown(350);
```

The search_zip_code.html.erb, which just contains:

```
<%= render 'form-zip' %>
```

And finally, the _form-zip.html.erb partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for @add_zip, remote: true do |z| %>
   <%= z.input :street %>
<% end %>
```

The good news is that the zip param is being correctly passed to search_zip_code method.

But the partial isn't being rendered: I've put breakpoints in all these erb files. The search_zip_code.js.erb is being reached, but the search_zip_code.html.erb and, of course, the _form-zip.html.erb, are not.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Guilherme

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try with the following code for the nested form

```
<%= form_for @object, url => { controller: 'controller', action: 'create', method: :get } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```